# IOS 7 Crash with missing proxy identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-sNv-dx-F0w

Tags: ios, crash, identifier

Once again I have hit the wall.  I can reliably produce the crash 
which you see below, but don't know how to interpret the result.
It seems the problem occurs at

```
Missing proxy for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-sNv-dx-F0w
```

According to what I've read, this may have something to do with
a misconfigured storyboard.  However, I have no idea of how find

```
UpstreamPlaceholder-sNv-dx-F0w
```

Any ideas on this?  Is this indeed the offending item?

PS.  Here is how I produce the crash: go from the main view (poems) to the author view.  Search for an author.  Delete one. Cancel search.  Go to main (poem) view.  Then switch to Category view. CRASH!  Poem, author, category are models backed by Core Data.  Each has its 
on view controller.

```
2013-11-08 08:19:39.137 Verz[82005:70b]   HERE IS OCCoreDataVC, viewdidLoad
2013-11-08 08:19:39.172 Verz[82005:70b]   OCCDTVC, setupTableView
2013-11-08 08:19:39.174 Verz[82005:70b]   Current date/time: 2013-11-08 13:19:39 +0000
2013-11-08 08:19:39.175 Verz[82005:70b]   Housekeeping, last time was 2013-11-08 13:06:59 +0000
2013-11-08 08:19:39.175 Verz[82005:70b] *** Here is MainVC (viewDidLoad
2013-11-08 08:19:39.176 Verz[82005:70b] ***  MVC, self.editing = 0
2013-11-08 08:19:39.177 Verz[82005:70b] *** In OCCoreDataTVC, self.numberInSelection = 9
2013-11-08 08:19:39.178 Verz[82005:70b] *** Here is configurePredicate in MainC
2013-11-08 08:19:47.171 Verz[82005:70b]   HERE IS OCCoreDataVC, viewdidLoad
2013-11-08 08:19:47.184 Verz[82005:70b]   OCCDTVC, setupTableView
2013-11-08 08:19:47.184 Verz[82005:70b] *** In OCCoreDataTVC, self.numberInSelection = 6
2013-11-08 08:19:47.185 Verz[82005:70b] *** Here is configurePredicate in AuthorVC
2013-11-08 08:19:50.339 Verz[82005:70b]   OCCDTVC, searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch
2013-11-08 08:19:51.624 Verz[82005:70b] *** Here is configurePredicate in AuthorVC
2013-11-08 08:19:51.998 Verz[82005:70b] *** Here is configurePredicate in AuthorVC
2013-11-08 08:19:58.410 Verz[82005:70b]   AVC -- I will delete the author Samuel Taylor Coleridge
2013-11-08 08:20:11.389 Verz[82005:70b] *** Here is configurePredicate in AuthorVC
2013-11-08 08:20:11.651 Verz[82005:70b] *** End search, now self.editing set to 0 -- but maybe this obscures a bug
2013-11-08 08:20:15.793 Verz[82005:70b] *** In OCCoreDataTVC, self.numberInSelection = 8
2013-11-08 08:20:15.794 Verz[82005:70b] *** Here is configurePredicate in MainC
2013-11-08 08:20:23.194 Verz[82005:70b]   HERE IS OCCoreDataVC, viewdidLoad
2013-11-08 08:20:23.194 Verz[82005:70b] *** I am about to crash!
2013-11-08 08:20:23.197 Verz[82005:70b] Missing proxy for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-sNv-dx-F0w
2013-11-08 08:20:23.197 Verz[82005:70b] Missing proxy for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-yQQ-L6-p1p
2013-11-08 08:20:23.209 Verz[82005:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIProxyObject 0xb473060> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key searchBar.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ff75e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01be68b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x020876a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x013389ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x012a4cfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x012a4253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x0130670a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x00687a15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf87d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x01ff2b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x0068656e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x004f8605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    12  UIKit                               0x004f8dad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    13  UIKit                               0x006a111e -[UITableViewController loadView] + 80
    14  UIKit                               0x004f90ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    15  UIKit                               0x004f95b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    16  UIKit                               0x006a0ea8 -[UITableViewController tableView] + 36
    17  UIKit                               0x006a196b -[UITableViewController setEditing:animated:] + 91
    18  UIKit                               0x006a1f1b -[UITableViewController tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:] + 49
    19  UIKit                               0x004becbb -[UITableView _sendDidEndEditingForIndexPath:] + 69
    20  UIKit                               0x004d5a1f -[UITableView _endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete:] + 316
    21  UIKit                               0x004cc8bb -[UITableView willMoveToSuperview:] + 83
    22  UIKit                               0x004403cf __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 176
    23  UIKit                               0x00440238 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 70
    24  UIKit                               0x0045c6bf -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 84
    25  UIKit                               0x0077c1e9 -[UISearchDisplayController _destroyManagedTableView] + 143
    26  UIKit                               0x0077af88 -[UISearchDisplayController dealloc] + 130
    27  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf7692 _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 268
    28  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf8adf -[NSObject release] + 25
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x01f78cb0 CFRelease + 272
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x01fabc92 -[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 82
    31  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf7692 _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 268
    32  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf8adf -[NSObject release] + 25
    33  UIKit                               0x004f7b65 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1577
    34  UIKit                               0x006a0e1a -[UITableViewController dealloc] + 276
    35  Verz                                0x0000f7d1 -[RHCoreDataTableViewController dealloc] + 161
    36  UIKit                               0x004f4975 -[UIViewController release] + 89
    37  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf6e97 objc_release + 71
    38  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf6e3e objc_storeStrong + 39
    39  Verz                                0x000072d9 -[ModelController setTvc:] + 57
    40  Verz                                0x00022a9b -[OCCoreDataTableViewController viewDidLoad] + 235
    41  UIKit                               0x004f9318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    42  UIKit                               0x004f95b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    43  UIKit                               0x005133e2 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 778
    44  UIKit                               0x005200c7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    45  UIKit                               0x00520cb9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    46  UIKit                               0x0065a181 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    47  UIKit                               0x00450267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    48  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bf881f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    49  QuartzCore                          0x001792ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    50  QuartzCore                          0x0016d0d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    51  QuartzCore                          0x0016cf40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    52  QuartzCore                          0x000d4ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    53  QuartzCore                          0x000d5e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    54  QuartzCore                          0x000d6544 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x01fbf4ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x01fbf41f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    57  CoreFoundation                      0x01f9d344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    58  CoreFoundation                      0x01f9cac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    59  CoreFoundation                      0x01f9c8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    60  GraphicsServices                    0x036469e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    61  GraphicsServices                    0x03646809 GSEventRun + 104
    62  UIKit                               0x003e5d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    63  Verz                                0x000026bd main + 141
    64  libdyld.dylib                       0x032e870d start + 1
    65  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: An interesting fact: if I search in one of the three views (Poem, Author, Category), switch to another, do the same, repeat --- no crash.  Likewise if I delete an item in one view, switch to another, delete an item in that view, switch to another, etc., repeat, repeat -- no crash.  But if I go from Poems to, say, Author, search, delete, switch then  switch to Poems, then to Category, I get the crash.  Works every time.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with my app whereby if I did a search on a tableview, deleted one of the items, canceled out of search mode and then clicked the back button, I would see the same error mentioned above.  Deleting an item and clicking back without performing the search step would result in everything working correctly and no crash occurring.  After a great deal of trial and error, I was able to resolve this issue by setting my search bar text to empty when the cancel search button is clicked.   Clicking on the cancel search button fires searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch so I added self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.Text = @""; to that method which stopped the error from occurring.